# MVC View tightly coupled, defies MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

MVC is loosely coupled for which MVC is used.
Controller - Model - View are **loosely coupled** so testing is easy.

But when we use tightly coupled views i.e. view **tightly coupled to model**, then how come View are independent and not related to model.

Tightly coupled View will depend on Model and it will be same as Web forms where .aspx page will be dependent on its page behind code. So testing will be an issue on View.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing strongly typed with tightly coupled.  They are two different things.

There is no problem with strongly typing a model to a view.  This is not like a code behind, because code behinds have events, overloads, and other kinds of logic.  Models are typically strictly data in MVC.

The view presents the model, and that's it.  It has to know what the model is in order for it to render it.

Because the view does not depend on a specific instance, it's not tightly coupled.  You can pass in any object that implements the strongly typed contract.

Answer (score 1):

Loose coupling doesn't mean loose contracts. The contracts are explicit.

The View is coupled against a contract, not an implementation, so it can display anything that fulfills the contract.

1. You can mockup a Model and render it with the View to test the View and the contract without the real Model.
2. The View and the Model can be independently instantiated.
3. You can modify one without understanding the other, as long as the contract is preserved.
4. The same Model can be rendered with various views (WPF, MVC Razor, ExtJS, WCF/Remote Client).

MVC is not the same as web forms. There is usually little or no code in the view. If there is, it is concerned with display/rendering, not data or logic. Most of the code you see in webform pages gets moved into the controller or the Model/ModelView in MVC.

Comment: Uhh.. what?  You can't do duck typing on strongly typed models.  You can only do it on dynamic models, which are not strongly typed.  Most people use strongly typed models where the model type is explicitly defined in the view with an @model statement.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - Yeh I had dynamic models in mind when I wrote that, but now that you call me on it, I realize most of the projects I write lately in ASP.NET MVC use strongly typed views, except for the odd case. I spent quite a few years with MVC in Web Work and Struts2 using dynamically bound views, and when I first transitioned to ASP.NET MVC 2 and 3, I used ViewData and ViewBag a lot before moving to strongly typed. It never really sunk into my brain. I mean I knew how @ model works, but when I think MVC Views I still think dynamic binding capability.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net MVC can be as loosely or as tightly coupled as much as you, the application architect, want it to.

If you type the view to a concrete model class, then the view is tightly coupled with the type of the model,  however if you type the view to an interface, or don't type it at all and use dynamic typing then it is loosely coupled.

The same goes for the controller and the model, you can instantiate a concrete model class in the controller (tight), or you can use a model interface and a configurable model factory (loose).

The bottom line is that ASP.Net MVC *framework* isn't there to solve coupling issues, it merely provides a framework for a web application architecture which utilizes the MVC *pattern*. The pattern itself was designed for separation of concerns and a responsibility-based architecture, it has nothing to do with coupling.

Answer (score 0):

A strong typed model for a view doesn't mean view is tightly coupled to model. You can have multiple views use the same model. Use a dynamic model if you don't like the concept of a strong typed model.

With you webform aspx page, you can't really easily unit test the code behind. As in MVC, it is very easy to unit test the controller.